# ubuntu restarting nginx nginx [fail]

Tags: nginx

it's my first time to use `nginx` and i tried to search on the web to fix this question...

```
root@VM-176-248-ubuntu:/# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

root@VM-176-248-ubuntu:/# tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log 
2016/04/28 19:00:54 [emerg] 15475#0: directive "try_files" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/micro-blog_nginx.conf:8
2016/04/28 19:01:33 [emerg] 15549#0: directive "try_files" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/micro-blog_nginx.conf:8
2016/04/28 19:15:00 [notice] 16436#0: signal process started
2016/04/28 19:22:30 [notice] 16969#0: signal process started

root@VM-176-248-ubuntu:/# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                        [fail]
```

could anybody tell me how can figure it out?

Comment: What is the question? According to warnings you have missed ';' on line 8 in `micro-blog_nginx.conf`.

Comment: The file *micro-blog_nginx.conf* is probably lacking a delimiter.

Comment: Can you post line 8 of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/micro-blog_nginx.conf`?

Comment: sorry i figure it out . i use `ps -e` and find there were two process of nginx and i use `kill -HUP` to kill them. And `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` it works.

Answer (score 0):

i use `ps -e` find there were two process of nginx is running.
use `kill -HUP <pid>` to kill them. problem has been solved